# Tutorial on how to connect a website login to logging in with Scatter Desktop?

Tags: javascript, scatter, authorization, dapp-development

I have a website with the ability to login with your username / password. But I want to create a way to login with Scatter Desktop. Are there any tutorials on how one can go about doing this?

My main questions are:

- How does my website launch the Scatter Desktop application?
- When logging in, does the scatter desktop reveal the user's private key or what type of "unique" identifier does it give back to my website?